# Windows rename files recursive

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm a bit stuck here, I created an easy file to zip folders with a special name.
So, lets say we are looking for folders with the name "tozip", but the name of the zipped file shall be the subfolder name + folder name.
e.g.
all files in C:/test/somefolder/123456/tozip/* shall be added to the file "123456_tozip.7z"

what I currently have is:

```
for /R /d /r %%i in (tozip*) do (
 7za a -tzip "%%i.7z" "%%i" -mx3
)
```

but this doesn't add the name of the n-1 folder to the filename. I saw, that I can extract e.g. the Filename by %%~nxi or the complete path, but unfortunately not the information I need. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Where is the zip (`.7z`) file: in `tozip\`, or higher up the directory tree?

Comment: Just a side question: `-tzip` means you are using the zip compression methods and not 7z. But your archive will have the `.7z` extension. Is this intended?

Comment: Strange that it does not throw an error with the two /R switches.

Comment: @AFH one directory tree higher

Comment: @nixda thank you, this it not that important, but thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: @Squasman copy paste error, sorry! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close and you even have the right idea but you need to take it one step further. Once you find the `tozip` directory you can then put that path into another `FOR` command to get the parent folder of the `tozip` folder.

Here is the code based on your example.

```
@echo off
for /D /R C:\test\ %%G in (tozip*) do (
    FOR %%H IN ("%%G\..") DO echo %%~nxH 
)
pause
```

Comment: ouch, that hurts... I wasn't aware, that it is that easy, thank you for your help!

Comment: I was trying to work out how to parse out the last element of the directory path: adding `\..` is a much neater solution!